# Import variables into functions from external file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that is rather long, uses several different data sources and can go wrong at many different stages. Having to restart the whole process from the beginning each time some error in the input data is discovered is not too much fun so I though I would save variables (actually paths to created data files) to a backup file then read in this file and pick up where I left off. Unfortunately

```
from previousrun import *
```

only imports the variables locally and I can't use import in each function as Python tells me its not allowed at module level. Is there any way of importing an unknown number of variables from another file and have them globally available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just attach all the parameters you want to save to an object and then use the `pickle` module to handle serialization?

```
>>> class Save(object): pass
...
>>> s = Save()
>>> s.foo = 'foo'
>>> s.bar = 42
>>> import pickle
>>> fp = open('save.pickle', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(s, fp)
>>> fp.close()
>>>
>>> fp2 = open('save.pickle', 'rb')
>>> s2 = pickle.load(fp2)
>>> s2.foo
'foo'
>>> s2.bar
42
>>>
```

Comment: But doesn't pickle require you to read in each variable explicitly? If I don't know when the previous run is going to end in error I can't know which variables to read in.

Comment: That's why I'm attaching them to a `Save` object (should probably have been called `Session`..).  Then the `except:` handler can do the `pickle.dump(..)`, and your startup code can do the `pickle.load(..)`

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. One odd thing not specific to this solution: global and local aren't set in stone. I tried several solutions, including this one, where the variable(s) were set outside of the main() function and it worked for a small, test script only to fail on my larger script. It seems that local variables can be global as long as the script doesn't exceed a certain size. This seems very odd to me. I haven't tested this thoroughly but from the few examples I have run this seems to be the case. Of course, I could be missing some other confounding factor in my larger script, maybe.

Comment: No, local variables are always local, and global variables should be avoided (because they make it much more difficult to reason about a chunk of the program without considering the entire application, and if you ever need to multitask they will be immediate bottlenecks).  If you truly do have computation state that evolves, then either encapsulating the computations as methods on a "Computation" object that holds the state, or passing the state around as a parameter (i.e. `def step_5(computation, arguments..)`) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your function:

```
`locals().update(importlib.import_module("importlib").__dict__)`
```

and `import importlib`.